# Atom: Can't search for Packages or Themes in the Install Packages section of Settings

Tags: python, search, package, atom-editor

I'm new to Atom (and relatively new to programming) and I just installed it about a few hours ago. I was trying to set it up by installing some new packages and themes in the Install Packages section of Settings. It was working fine for a while but now I'm getting errors when I try to search. A red box appears below the search field with this error:

```
Searching for “pre” failed.Hide output…
i.filter is not a function
[object Object]
```

I'm on Windows 10 with Atom 1.49.0 x64 installed. Python 3.8 is also installed with the path set. It seems to run code fine. I even found a theme on the Atom website and was able to install from there, I just can't search. I feel like I messed something up.

I've searched Google, Stack Overflow, and the discussion section for Atom and I'm finding nothing that fixes this issue. I've restarted my computer and uninstalled/reinstalled Atom. I will say that after I reinstalled Atom, it still had all my setting changes I had made and it had all the packages that I had already installed still there. So maybe the uninstall didn't remove those with the program. But I wouldn't know where to go to clear that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Quick recommendation: Abandon Atom and go with VS Code if you can. I got tired of struggling with issues like this when using Atom professionally. VS code is far less error-prone for Python development.

Comment: I'd recommend going to the specific package's GitHub repo and file an issue over there.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have VS. I'll give it a try too.

Comment: Just use apm list, apm install package, etc... and it works fine — even when the Atom package server has problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atom Server seems to have a problem today.
Packages that were installed well a few days ago are not available today.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: You were right. I just needed to wait. Thank you for help!

Comment: Just use `apm list`, `apm install package`, etc... and it works fine — even when the Atom package server has problems.